# How to deploy solution to other applications which is already existing in the farm?

Tags: solution-package

I have a solution already deployed in farm for an application. Now I have added new application in the farm and I would need to use the same solution for the newly added web application as well.
Is there any possibility of doing the same without retracting the existing solution?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do that either from the Central Administration (System Settings, Farm Solution, click on your solution, and then "Deploy": you can select the ttarget Web application), or from a SharePoint PowerShell console (`Install-SPSolution -Identity <WSP_NAME> -WebApplication <Web_App_URL> [-GACDeployment]`).

Answer (score 3):

No need to retract the solution. Just install it in your new web application using PowerShell.

```
Install-SPSolution -WebApplication "[Site Collection URL]" -GACDeployment  -Identity xxx.wsp
```